# Как сойденить webrtc (node.js) с php?

Tags: php, node.js, webrtc

У меня есть 2 разных части проекта, одна сделана на node.js - это p2p webrtc видео чат, вторая на php, это парсер. Как я могу сойденить эти две части в один проект?

Comment: Парсить webrtc ?

Comment: @ArchDemon, не, я на php парсю страницу и мне надо чтобы парсилось и шел видео чат на одной странице.

Answer (score 0):

Например, создать API на PHP и взаимодействовать через него с Node приложением, чтобы передавать между ними данные.
Так же можете попробовать использовать сокеты или Named Pipes, чтобы передавать данные между двумя процессами.

По сокетам, вот для php:
https://packagist.org/packages/workerman/phpsocket.io
вот для ноды:

```
npm install socket.io
```